# representation of a group and its center

Tags: group-theory, category-theory, representation-theory, fusion-categories

Let $G$ be a finite group and let $Z(G)$ be its center. Let $C=\mathrm{Rep}(G)$ be the category of finite dimensional representation of $G$. Let $D$ be the fusion subcategory of $C$ generated by $V \otimes V^*$ for each (representative of isomorphism class of) simple object of $C$.

**I want to show that $D=\mathrm{Rep}(G/Z(G))$.**

First I thought that for an irreducible representation $V$, we have $V \otimes V^* \cong \mathrm{Hom}(V, V)\cong k$, where $k$ is a base field. But it seems that this argument is wrong by considering dimensions.

I appreciate any help.

Comment: Why would it be trivial? Simple objects of $C$ are the irreducible representations $V$, and $V\otimes V^*$ has dimension the square of that of $V$.

Comment: @KevinCarlson Thank you. I edited the question.

Comment: When you write $\text{Hom}$ you need to pay careful attention to the implicit ring $R$. What ring should these homomorphisms commute with?

Comment: Tensor Categories By Pavel Etingof, Shlomo Gelaki, Dmitri Nikshych, Victor Ostrik seems to claim that it's true, i don't see a complete proof tere though.

Comment: @BenjaminGadoua Could you tell me in which page I can find the claim in Tensor Categories?

Comment: I don't actually own a copy of it... but hilariously I googled for fusion subcategory and found a link to the book on the appropriate page.